# TypeError: date is undefined in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

But the firebug shows date is undefined in the bootstrap-datepicker.js file in the following line.

```
var parts = date.split(format.separator)
```

javascript file and css are working properly

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/datepicker.css" type="text/css"/>
```

And Initialized the date picker using

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
```

Comment: I believe that lack the value of its field

Comment: Can we see your <input class="datepicker"></input> ?

Comment: can u explain more.. i couldn't understand

Comment: <input type='text' id='dates' class='datepicker' data-date-format=\"yyyy-mm-dd\" readonly>

Comment: in the calender there is no value element .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem Was Due to older bootstrap-datepicker.js . After Replacing bootstrap-datepicker.js with new its working properlly.