# Bootstrap Datepicker is not Working .Using BootStrap 3.3.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

First I have downloaded the zip file from  bellow link
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/
and i got the following structure 
1.CSS folder - datepicker.css
2.JS folder-bootstrap-datepicker.js
3.less folder - datepicker.less

then i have added it to my asp.net mvc 4 project structure
and in the index.cshtml i have added the references 
then bellow is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Contents/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Contents/bootstrap/js/npm.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Contents/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker9').datepicker();
            $('#datetimepicker10').datepicker();
            $("#datetimepicker9").onclick ("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#datetimepicker10').data("DateTimePicker").setDate(e.date);
            });
            $("#datetimepicker10").onclick("dp.change", function (e) {
               $('#datetimepicker9').data("DateTimePicker").setDate(e.date);
            });
        });
    </script>


<div class="searchDatePickerRow">
            <div class="searchFrmDate">
                <form class="formMargin" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="searchToDate">
                <form class="formMargin" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date " id="datetimepicker10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but when i click on the calander image datepicker is not working.
I have followd the bellow links
[How do I get bootstrap-datepicker to work with Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887950/how-do-i-get-bootstrap-datepicker-to-work-with-bootstrap-3)
[Bootstrap-Datetimepicker Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846525/bootstrap-datetimepicker-not-working)
but not getting any success.In the above link it is mentioned to add datetimepicker.js and moment.js but from where i will get this file.

Comment: On the page, try this code in console and check what error it gives. `$('#datetimepicker9').datepicker();`

Comment: Its  showing following error  TypeError- Date is undefind

Comment: I have updated the above comment  TypeError- Date is undefind

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675206/typeerror-date-is-undefined-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.3.1 and i have downloaded datepicker from the  bellow link http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: The link also has markup for BS 2 than BS 3.3. You need to get the version compatible with BS 3.

Comment: [Use this](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19275903/473016).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add `bootstrap-datepicker.css`
Add the `datepicker.css` after `bootstrap.css.` You can get it from this url
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

then call this javascript below:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the class datepicker or the data attributes in your input class. you have to add this in your input tag.

```
<input class="datepicker" data-provide="datepicker">
```

Comment: Added the above class and  as well as data-provider but it is not working